# CartThrob Subscriptions module issue

Tags: cartthrob

I 'm using CartThrob Subscriptions module. In this module area, while clicking at "Add Subscription" button, I 'm getting the message "*To create new subscriptions for existing customers, you must already have member data stored with the payment processor. You currently have no payment vaults available for any customers*"

Screenshot is here:
[image]

Can anyone help me if s(he) faced such a thing and resolve it. I am really stuck here and couldn't understand what more settings I need to do.

I 'll highly appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the user either needs to *purchase* the subscription so they agree to the recurring payment and provide their card details with the transaction or if it's for an existing member then they need to have paid before with a payment gateway which supports the token vault system. These include:

- Authorize.net (CIM)
- eWay (Token Payments)
- Payleap (SCM)
- Sage (Token)
- Stripe

They basically securely store the credit card details in their vaults so purchases can be made at a later date without needing to enter in those CC details again.

It may be that the payment gateway that you're using doesn't support the token vault system or it may be that the customer either hasn't purchased from the store before. In which case you may need to setup a subscription plan and then get them to *purchase* this on the front-end with one of the above payment gateways. That should see future subscriptions go through fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I 'm using "Sagepay Europe Offsite (Server)" gateway from CT's Payment settings. But for now as Test mode and I am not sure if it facilitates for recurring payment in test mode. It may also be cause. Please let me know your thought on it. I have setup the subscription plan and vault system.

Comment: I think with SagePay that you actually need it set it up as a separate feature to your account where you [pay for the number of tokens in use per month](http://www.sagepay.com/token-system). Have you set this up in addition to their standard payment gateway?

Comment: The token system is set up for that SagePay account but still facing same issue. Could you please give me some pointers.